# How to match all spaces which does not end with a character using regex?

Tags: regex

I have a engine which takes in a **row regex** (which extracts a single row) and a **common column regex** (which extracts columns from each row)

but I am having trouble with getting a **common column regex** which can extract the below example text into columns with common indexes (which is done by the engine)

Example text: you can [test it here](http://regexr.com?31lgb)

```
/misc/qk12              (innfs1:/vol/fs06/qk12  ) : 314572800 total allocated Kb
                                                  62636476 free allocated Kb
                                                  251936324 used allocated Kb
                                                        81 % allocation used
/home/psum           (innfs2_42:/vol/goshihome/goshihome/home/psum) : 2349649104 total allocated Kb
                                                  405498596 free allocated Kb
                                                  1944150508 used allocated Kb
                                                        83 % allocation used
/home/aman           (innfs2_42:/vol/goshihome/goshihome/home/aman) : 2349649104 total allocated Kb
                                                  405498596 free allocated Kb
                                                  1944150508 used allocated Kb
                                                        83 % allocation used
/u01                   (/dev/vg00/u01vol      ) :  9559429 total allocated Kb
                                                   4077136 free allocated Kb
                                                   5482293 used allocated Kb
                                                        58 % allocation used
```

Right now in the [test](http://regexr.com?31lgb)

You can see the 1st 2 rows works good with `\s+` which divides each row into `0,1,3,7,11,15` indexes of relevant information, but it fails for the next 2 rows, as there is a extra space in `(innfs1:/vol/fs06/qk12  )`.

So I was wondering if someone could help me with a regex which will match all spaces which does not end with a immediate character `)`.

Comment: And that's why I love PowerShell where you get proper objects ;)

Comment: @Joey: it's a `df -k` output from a HP-UX box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a positive lookahead at the end of your Regex.  The positive lookahead part is non-capturing, but it will help narrow your matches:

`\s+(?!\s*\))`

The `(?!     )` construct is a *group*, defined by the round brackets, and the `?!` part create a non-capturing lookahead, meaning that the group is used as part of the match, but the content matched by that group is not included in the output of the match.

The `\s*` creates a "zero or more spaces" and the `\)` expects a bracket after the spaces.

Reference to very good page with explanations on lookahead / lookbehind (lookaround) Regex expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to negate the bracket. (\s*?!\))